# VB: Pass 2D array into Sub

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function

I have a 2D array whose size inside the () is not static. Aka the code will assign the size later. I want to pass into my function this array so I can perform a lot of code using it.

My array:

```
'generate Ingredient array
Dim Ingredients(checkCount2 - 1, 3) As String
Dim maxDim0 As Integer = UBound(Ingredients, 1)
Dim maxDim1 As Integer = UBound(Ingredients, 2)
```

I have tried the following:

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To maxDim0
     For j As Integer = 0 To maxDim1
        GenerateNewImport(Ingredients(i, j), F_IDCode, F_Description, F_VersionDate, F_VersionNumber)
     Next j
 Next i
```

OR

```
GenerateNewImport(Ingredients, F_IDCode, F_Description, F_VersionDate, F_VersionNumber)
```

OR

```
GenerateNewImport(Ingredients(), F_IDCode, F_Description, F_VersionDate, F_VersionNumber)
```

OR

```
GenerateNewImport(Ingredients(checkCount2-1, 3), F_IDCode, F_Description, F_VersionDate, F_VersionNumber)
```

and etc but I keep getting errors like:

```
(Ingredients, ... :   Value of type '2-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to '1-dimension
```

and etc

My function is:

```
Sub GenerateNewImport(ByVal Ingredients(,) As String, ByVal F_IDCode As String, ByVal F_Description As String, ByVal F_VersionDate As String, ByVal F_VersionNumber As String)

End Sub
```

**Any suggestions on how to pass my array into the function call?**

Referenced below and many others:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dk93f6e(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: `GenerateNewImport(Ingredients, F_IDCode, F_Description, F_VersionDate, F_VersionNumber)` is working in my test case.

Comment: Sorry, this method `Sub GenerateNewImport(ByVal Ingredients(,) As String, ByVal F_IDCode As String, ByVal F_Description As String, ByVal F_VersionDate As String, ByVal F_VersionNumber As String)` can be called using one of your examples, `GenerateNewImport(Ingredients, F_IDCode, F_Description, F_VersionDate, F_VersionNumber)` ... what was the actual problem?

Comment: @Verdolino the issue was I couldn't pass my array inside my function . It gave the error I mentioned. Romulus001 answered my question. Issue was that my function itself was not checking for my 2D array correctly even though I was passing it correctly using `GenerateNewImport(Ingredients, ..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ByVal Ingredients(,) As String
```

has to replaced by

```
ByRef Ingredients As String(,)
```

EDIT : I replaced the keyword **ByVal** by **ByRef**

Comment: That fixed my error. So now I can call `Ingredients, ...` in my function call just fine. Thank you! I don't work with 2D arrays much so felt stupid that I missed this

Comment: @narue1992 : just edited my post, to pass an array as parameter (or an object), it's better to use the keyword **ByRef**

Comment: An array is already a reference type, so `ByVal` or `ByRef` doesn't really matter.

Comment: No it does not. [How to: Pass an Array to a Procedure or Property (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63y5ksfs(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You said you tried to call

```
Sub GenerateNewImport(ByVal Ingredients(,) As String, ByVal F_IDCode As String, ByVal F_Description As String, ByVal F_VersionDate As String, ByVal F_VersionNumber As String)

End Sub
```

with this code

```
GenerateNewImport(Ingredients, F_IDCode, F_Description, F_VersionDate, F_VersionNumber)
```

but that combination is actually correct. The accepted answer has to deal with changing the signature from `Ingredients(,) As String` to `Ingredients As String(,)` and using `ByRef` because it's an array. However, arrays are passed as reference types anyway so this is inconsequential. And the placement of `(,)` in either case is the same

Here's a simple example showing how to pass a multidimensional array to a method, and that you had no problem in the first place.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim ingredients(1, 1) As String
        ingredients(0, 0) = "a"
        ingredients(0, 1) = "b"
        ingredients(1, 0) = "c"
        ingredients(1, 1) = "d"
        Signature1(ingredients)
        Signature2(ingredients)
        Signature3(ingredients)
        Signature4(ingredients)
        For i As Integer = ingredients.GetLowerBound(0) To ingredients.GetUpperBound(0)
            For j As Integer = ingredients.GetLowerBound(1) To ingredients.GetUpperBound(1)
                Console.WriteLine(ingredients(i, j))
            Next
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub Signature1(ByVal ingredients As String(,))
        ingredients(0, 0) = UCase(ingredients(0, 0))
        Console.WriteLine("You called Signature1")
    End Sub

    Sub Signature2(ByVal ingredients(,) As String)
        ingredients(0, 1) = UCase(ingredients(0, 1))
        Console.WriteLine("You called Signature2")
    End Sub

    Sub Signature3(ByRef ingredients As String(,))
        ingredients(1, 0) = UCase(ingredients(1, 0))
        Console.WriteLine("You called Signature3")
    End Sub

    Sub Signature4(ByRef ingredients(,) As String)
        ingredients(1, 1) = UCase(ingredients(1, 1))
        Console.WriteLine("You called Signature4")
    End Sub

End Module
```

with output showing that all the signatures are equivalent, and are all passing `ByRef`

> You called Signature1
>   
> You called Signature2
>   
> You called Signature3
>   
> You called Signature4
>   
> A
>   
> B
>   
> C
>   
> D

Comment: I wasn't aware that my actual function was the issue. That is why I accepted the first answer. I was happy however to realize that my actual function call was correct. Thank you for your example as well. The example set up does help.